# what will happen to the uniform matroid $U_{2,m}$ if we remove an element from it?

Tags: graph-theory, lattice-orders, combinatorial-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics, uniform-matroids

I am trying to figure out what will happen to the uniform matroid $U_{2,m}$ if we remove an element e from it, where e is neither a coloop nor a loop. I am guessing that it will become disconnected but I am not sure from this.

A uniform matroid is defined as: If m and n are non-negative integers with $m \leq n.$ Let $E$ be an $n$-element set and $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of $m$-element subsets of $E.$ Then it is easy to check that $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of bases of a matroid on $E.$  We denote this matroid by $U_{m,n}$ and call it the uniform matroid of rank $m$ on an $n$-element set.

I also know that the drawing of a $U_{2,5}$ matroid is just a line segment with 5 dots on it representing the vertices from a picture online, is this always the drawing of a uniform matroid $U_{2,m}$ matroid?

Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should note that $U_{2, n}$ has no loops, since the rank of any singleton is 1. If $n\geq 3$, $U_{2, n}$ has no coloops, since every element is in a circuit (any 3 element set containing said element). Thus, the condition of $e$ not being a loop or coloop is irrelevant unless $n=2$, in which case both elements are coloops. So let $n\geq 3$.

Now, recall that given a matroid $M$ with elements $E$ and an element $e\in E$, the matroid $M\backslash e$ has for independent sets those of $M$ contained in $E-e$, or equivalently, the bases of $M\backslash e$ are the bases of $M$ contained in $E-e$. Hence, $U_{2, n}$ minus an element is isomorphic to $U_{2, n-1}$. Hence, the resulting matroid is not connected if and only if $n=3$. In general, $U_{m,n}$ is connected unless $m\in \{0,n\}$.

Now, if you were to delete more than one element, you are bound to decrease the rank of the uniform matroid at some point, as you at some point will not have enough elements to keep the rank up. In general, for the uniform matroid $U_{m, n}$ and a set $T$ of $t$ elements,

$$
U_{m, n}\backslash T \cong \begin{cases}U_{n-t, n-t}, & \text{if } n-m\leq t\leq n,\\ U_{m, n-t}, & \text{if } t<n-m.
\end{cases}
$$
For instance, if we delete an element from $U_{2,2}$ (which is necessarily a coloop) we obtain $U_{1,1}$.

Indeed, the drawing of $U_{2, m}$ is in general a line with $m$ points. Lines in such matroid drawings are rank 2 flats.

Comment: Why the drawing is just a line?

Comment: This is just convention for how we draw matroids. Matroids of rank at most four are drawn as follows: you put a point for each non-loop element, parallel elements are drawn next to each other, three elements forming a circuit are on a line, and four elements forming a circuit are on a plane. Loop elements are drawn somewhere to the side of the figure, usually in a box, indicating these are loops. It is harder to do this with higher ranks, because it is hard to draw in dimension four or higher. James Oxley's book describes this process with some examples.

Comment: I did not quite well understand why the figure is a line? Is it because our bases are always  consisting of 2 points in $U_{2,m}$?

Comment: oh I got you because any set of 3 elements or more is a circuit in our matroid, right?

Comment: Yes. Any three points form a circuit, so must be on a line. You can try drawing this for yourself, but the only way to do this is to put them all on a single line.

Comment: what will happen if we contract an element that is nether a loop nor a coloop? Will the matroid become containing a loop?

Comment: But fig. 1.8 in Oxley has a loop in it and it is a geometric representation of a rank 2 matroid, can you clarify this please?

Comment: @Hope I think at this point you ought to make a new post with your new questions (mainly so that people can actually find this information if they are looking for it).

Comment: but my last question is very related to the first line of your answer here, should I still post a new question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150503/discussion-between-mathieu-rundstrom-and-hope).